# Open spreadsheet with Google apps script web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We are linking an excel spreadsheet to a google sheets.
To open the correct sheet we want to use a webapp. 
How do we open the sheet from the web app?

To be specific, we need following code to open the spreadsheet with the function `openSheet(sheeturl)`. How do we do this?

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S3-u9fbS69JZntzLyCt9ynqeLpQVpJo78dsP55OnV_E/edit?usp=sharing");
  var sheeturl = sheet.getUrl();
  openSheet(sheeturl);  
}
```

Comment: Have you explored [embed files](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965#embed_files) - once you publish your sheet to the web, you get a code that can be used in an HTML file using Google Apps Script and then present it on a web app using `doGet()` function.

Comment: We really want to open the document itself, we need to do a load of work in it. I don't think an embedded version has all capabilities.

Comment: You should take a look at [this tutorial](https://wcmshelp.ucsc.edu/advanced/embedding-google/index.html), it shows you how to display the document in an iframe.

Comment: `var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1S3-u9fbS69JZntzLyCt9ynqeLpQVpJo78dsP55OnV_E");`

Comment: Where exactly would you like to open the spreadsheet, in a new browser tab?